# catkin_make can't seem to find package joyConfig

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I've attempted to install ROS on the raspi via the tutorial using the recommended ros-indigo-comm package via rosinstall_generator. In my catkin_ws I have these roscomm files (which all seem to build during a catkin_make... however the bluerov_apps cmake seems to be giving cmake errors such as sensor_msgs missing. So I rosinstall_generator that package as well but then run into pcl_conversions followed by a pcl_config missing error. I am just wondering if I followed the wrong path here because of the variety of errors.

EDIT: I commented out the pcl_conversions build dependency but now having issues with not being able to find joyConfig.cmake. With a little searching, I was able to find it in /opt/ros/indigo/share/joy/cmake... If i do an echo on $ROS_PACKAGE_PATH it has /opt/ros/indigo/share as a path...so why can't it find it and how can I point it in the right direction?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229668/catkin_make-can%27t-seem-to-find-package-joyconfig/) by [szutshi7](https://answers.ros.org/users/26342/szutshi7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-03-20

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a similar issue, simple solution (maybe not the cleanest) install all `pcl` and `joy` related pkgs, like:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-joy*
```

The `*Config.cmake` missing error massage suggest that the linker can't find some pkg.

---

Originally posted by [zweistein](https://answers.ros.org/users/4023/zweistein/) with karma: 231 on 2017-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jiashiwei](https://answers.ros.org/users/26780/jiashiwei/) on 2017-05-22**:
it really work! thanks!